# Using the which operator, find the matches where his score was an even number, and print the match numbers

Tags: r, vector

Virat scored 98,102,120,145,175,169,118,177,101,200 runs in the recent 10 test matches. Using the which operator, find the matches where his score was an even number, and print the match numbers.

I have tried the below code:

```
Virat_Scored  <- c(98,102,120,145,175,169,118,177,101,200)
a <- Virat_Scored %% 2 == 0
print(Virat_Scored[a])
```

What will the the correct or exact code for the above quesion.

Comment: You can just do `Virat_Scored[Virat_Scored %% 2 == 0]`.

Comment: Is there any  which operator, by which I can solve this

Comment: `Virat_Scored[which(Virat_Scored %% 2 == 0)]`

Answer (score 2):

Get the indexes of the even numbers using which

```
ind = which(Virat_Scored %% 2 == 0)
```

Then extract these from the Virat_Scored vector

```
Virat_Scored[ind] 
[1]  98 102 120 118 200
```

Answer (score 0):

Below worked for me:)

```
Virat_Scored  <- c(98,102,120,145,175,169,118,177,101,200)
which(Virat_Scored %% 2 == 0)
```